# What functions are continuous in the Wasserstein metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lipschitz-functions, optimal-transport

Consider the space $L_p(\mathbb{R})$ of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ with $p$<sup>th</sup> moments.  This set is a metric space under the $p$-Wasserstein metric $$W_p(\mu,\nu)^p=\inf_{Z=(X,Y):X\sim\mu,Y\sim\nu}{\mathbb{E}[d(X,Y)^p]}$$  Now, pick your favorite bounded continuous function $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$.  Then $f$ defines a function $f^*$ on $L_p$ via integration: $$f^*(\mu)=\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\mu}[f(X)]$$  (Fun exercise: prove that $f(X)$ has a first moment.)  In the course of solving [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450528/measurability-of-integral-with-respect-to-a-parameter-dependent-measure/4450717), I found myself asking: **is $f^*$ always continuous?**

If $f$ is Lipschitz, then the answer is "yes", by the argument given at the end of [my solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4450717/330413) to that problem.  But **is the claim true for non-Lipschitz functions?**  I am not sure.

On the one hand, my proof uses the Lipschitz constant in an essential way.

On the other, take $p=1$ for simplicity.  Choose $\mu_n(dx)=\frac{dx}{|nx|^3+1}$, so that $\mu$ only has moments of order $<2$ and let $f:C(\mathbb{R})$; $f(x)=|x|^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha<1$.  If there were a counterexample in the non-Lipschitz case, I would think that those choices of $f$ and $\mu_n$ should be it, for they are as badly-behaved as can be while still having enough moments.  Yet $\mu_n\overset{W_1}{\longrightarrow}\delta_0$ and $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\mu_n}[|X|^{\alpha}]\to0$.

Perhaps the problem is that the above non-counterexample is Lipschitz away from $0$, and I should look at functions that aren't Lipschitz on a more generic region — say, $f:C((-1,1))$; $f(x)=\sin{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$, with $\mu_n\overset{W_1}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{U}(\{-1,1\})$?  But I am not sure how to impose cutoff to regularize $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\mathcal{U}(\{-1,1\})}[f(X)]$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be trivially true, because $W$ metrises the weak topology on $L$?

Comment: @Tobsn: Does $W_2$ metrize that topology?  I'd take a proof of that or link to a source as an answer.

Comment: It does. That's a classical statement, you'll find in every reasonable text book on OT theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tobsn explained to me in the comments, it is a classical result that convergence in $W_p$ is equivalent to (combined) weak convergence (as $C_b^*$) and convergence of the $p$<sup>th</sup> moment.

The key idea missing from my argument is the following:

> If $f\in C_b$, then there exists $\{f_n\}_n,\{g_n\}_n\in(C_b\cap\mathrm{Lip}_b)^{\omega}$ such that $f_n\leq f\leq g_n$ (for any $n$) and $f_n,g_n\to f$ pointwise.

($\mathrm{Lip}_b$ denotes the space of bounded Lipschitz functions.)

That claim follows from e.g. supremal/infimal convolution, and implies weak convergence for $f$, via Fatou's lemma.

(H/T Villani, *Topics in Optimal Transportation* (2003), p. 217.)