# Measurability of family of probability distributions

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be complete separable metric spaces, endowed with their respective Borel sigma-algebras. Consider a family $\{P_x: x \in X\}$ of probability measures on $Y$, which in principle are not assumed to be dominated. When can we expect the map $x\mapsto P_x(A)$ to be measurable for all measurable sets $A\subseteq Y$?

I am primarily interested in a few concrete cases:

1. When $P_x$ is a a normal distribution for all $x\in X$.
2. When $Y$ is a space of functions, e.g. $Y=L^2[0,1]$.
3. When $Y$ is a product space $Y=Y_1\times Y_2$, and the dependence on $x$ is only present in the conditional distribution $P_x(Y_2|Y_1)$ (i.e. $P(Y_1)$ is constant w.r.t. $x$).

I feel this question is relevant because the measurability of $x\mapsto P_x(A)$ is often assumed in the study of posterior asymptotics in a Bayesian framework (see e.g. $\S1.3$ in *Bayesian nonparametrics* by Ghosh and Ramamoorthi or $\S10.4$ in *Asymptotic Statistics* by van der Vaart).

---

I am aware that Fubini's theorem might be useful for this problem, but a naive application only gives the measurability of
$$
x \mapsto \int_A dP_{\color{blue}{x'}} = P_{\color{blue}{x'}}(A)
$$
for each (fixed) ${\color{blue}{x'}} \in X$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450528/measurability-of-integral-with-respect-to-a-parameter-dependent-measure) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\mapsto P_x(A)$ is measurable then so is $x\mapsto \int f(y) dP_x(y)$ for all measurable functions $f:Y\to\mathbb R$ such that all integrals exist. (This is a standard result following from the approximation of measurable functions by simple function).

Let $\varphi:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be any non-measurable function, define $P_x$ as the normal distribution with mean $\varphi(x)$ and variance $1$ and take $f(y)=y$. Then $\phi(x)=\int f(y) dP_x(y)$.

Comment: Thank you. Since there are simple counterexamples such as this one, I wonder if there are any (relatively common) conditions such that measurability is guaranteed.